# Sharepoint 2010 custom 404 page - asp extension

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. It's replacing a legacy site built using asp.

As it's public facing and anonymous, we're implementing a custom 404 page. Strangely, this is not simple OOTB (like usual), but I did manage to deploy a 404 page and link it up using an event receiver. Perfect, works fine.

So, in testing I tried entering some random pages that didn't exist. It worked fine for .htm, .html, and .aspx. Next, I tried the .asp extension, as this is what all outstanding bookmarks / search engine links will be based from. Instead of the 404 page I got a blank page. I checked it out in Firebug, and the file was actually returned with a 404 header, but it has no content. Not good.

Anyone solved this problem? Is a custom http module the only way to go here??

As an aside, another strange behaviour is if you use a unknown extension it will render the html from your 404 page as text! **Edit**: Also, if you enter an extensionless folder that doesn't exist you get this same behaviour. Wow, this strange beast continues to vex me.

Thanks.

**Update**

Looks like a HttpModule is the only way to go here. I have this working - if anyone would like complete code let me know. I'd post it here, but the SO code formatter is mangling things.

web.config entry looks like the following:

```
<add name="PageNotFoundHttpModule" type="ProjectName.PageNotFoundHttpModule, ProjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fb507da11a891ef3" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010 ‘Page not found (404)’ page the way it should be](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-page-not-found-404/)

Comment: Yes, I'm working through that idea right now. I guess this is the only way then. Quite shocking, really.

Comment: I'm having trouble adding  the web.config entry - gettin "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid." - do you know of a blog on how to add the HttpModule? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I deployed the vs.net solution to the GAC - this is by default. I just added a class to my solution. Nothing special has to be done to have this included in the dll, right? Also, this is going in system.webServer > modules as it's integrated pipeline.

Comment: Tried that, same error. I used just the root namespace as this is the only class in the namespace for now.

Comment: Dang it, just needed the root namespace as well. IIS manager sorted this out for me. No need for the compilation > assemblies entry.I'll update my question with the entry. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule sure is the way to go. I followed this page to get it working

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-page-not-found-404/

However, the module only works if I leave out the precondition or else you will run into a blank page.